# Make AWS Step function Parameter Optional

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Is there a way to make AWS Step function parameter optional?
or
accept an expression to say if the value is passed pick the value else default it to a certain value?

Example:

Lets say my Parameters are defined as follows:

```
"Parameters": {
        "comment": "Selecting what I care about.",
        "MyDetails": {
          "size.$": "$.inputSize"
        }
      },
```

If I don't pass inputSize, the step function fails. is there a way to make this an optional parameter or have an expression like inputSize || 10 where 10 would be picked if nothing is passed

Comment: Woudn't something like this work: `$[?(@.inputSize)].inputSize`. If `inputSize` exist, it returns `inputSize`, otherwise an empty object or array is returned?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is **NO**.

Two things to note about Step Function state input/output and state InputPath/OutputPath

1. Input processing doesn't support default property values. All the properties have to come either from the previous state or as input to step function invocation. ([Input and Output processing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-input-output-filtering.html))
2. JsonPath can be used only to reference a property in InputPath or OutputPath. If a poperty is not present in the input or result an error is thrown. ([Reference Paths](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-paths.html#amazon-states-language-reference-paths))

**Suggestion**

My suggestion is to set the `inputSize` property to zero or a negative number either in previous state or during step function invocation (don't forget to pass it along various intermediate states). Then you can have a [choice state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html) where you can take different routes in your workflow depending upon the value of the `inputSize` property.

Another way could be to have a mandatory boolean property which tells if a particular property is present or not in the input or result. This can be helpful in the case we want to check for nullness of a property and take different routes in the workflow.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this myself by including an extra step.

So my StepFunction loops around back on itself, so the first time it's executed the value doesn't exist and I need to pass in 0, then increment it as it loops around.

```
"Prepare": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "TimeoutSeconds": 60,
  "Resource": "...",
  "ResultPath": "$.prepareResult",
  "Parameters": {
    "Runs.$": "$.prepareResult.runs"
  },
  ...
  "Next": "PrepareDecision"
},
```

The first time this is run `prepareResult` does not exist, so this throws an error when executed.

Once executed it returns a result which is appended to `prepareResult` and contains the value for `runs`.

To default the value I included a `PrepareDefaults` step, which is executed before this step.

```
"PrepareDefaults": {
  "Type": "Pass",
  "ResultPath": "$.prepareResult",
  "Parameters": {
    "runs": 0
  },
  "Next": "Prepare"
},
```

The parameters property is returned as is and assigned to the path `prepareResult` which allows it to exist on the next step.

When the StepFunction is executed, the default value of 0 is passed in.

*Note: On the PrepareDefaults state, you must set a ResultPath for the parameters to be assigned to, if you don't it will override /all/ the data in the current execution.*

*Note 2: You can use this method with Choice to say if a value exists go directly to state X, if the value doesn't exist go to Y to default it before going to X*